# Multi-Channel Funnel API - Unknown API or Version

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to get MCF data using an API, however getting an error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: analyticsmultichannelfunnel  version: v4
```

I am using the following code to connect:

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)
print("test")
analytics = build('mcf', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
print(analytics)
return analytics
```

any idea how I can solve it? Or where I can find a sample code for using MCF API in Python?

Answer (score 1):

The MCF API does not have a v4; see the [latest documentation for v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/libraries)